# Ошибка сборки приложения "None of the valid provisioning profiles include the devices:" в Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

Всем привет.
Пытаюсь собрать приложение в Xcode на iPad. На несколько разных iPhone получилось - на iPad нет. Выдает ошибку

> None of the valid provisioning profiles include the devices:
>   iPad.
>
> Xcode can attempt to fix this issue.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что не так?

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался, нужно было обновить лицензии в membercenter